# Problem ping a URL from C#

Tags: c#, exception, ping

My scenario:

When i ping with www.google.com it give the status Success, When i try to ping http://stackoverflow.com  i got an exception "An exception occurred during a Ping request." What is the reason? how can i solve?

```
using (Ping png = new Ping())
{
  PingReply pr = png.Send("http://stackoverflow.com");
  string status= pr.Status.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Joachim said, drop the protocol. If you read the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed.aspx ) you'd be aware that the ping object wants a host name or address, not a URI.

Answer (score 9):

Don't include the HTTP://, then it works fine.

Comment: Yes, HTTP:// just tells the browser what protocol to use, like HTTPS:// or FTP://

Comment: Ping still only works with IPs sent, not hostnames. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send.aspx) says you can use it though... Any idea on this?